# Set SelectedValue to 0 when garbage is entered in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a simple ComboBox which looks like following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ItemsCompColl}" 
          TextSearch.TextPath="ItemName"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ItemId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

    ........................

</ComboBox>
```

It works well. Now, I am using the ItemId property which is bound in SelectedValue to check if user has selected an appropriate item from comboBox or not.

**Issues:**

When user selects a value from ComboBox, the ItemId property is set to the Id of the Selected Item in ComboBox. After that if user goes to next Control and returns to ComboBox and enters some garbage value to ComboBox, the ItemId of ComboBox does not change, I mean it's not reset to "0". So, my validation fails and user succeeds in entering the garbage values.

Comment: Why not disallow manual entry and require a selection from the combobox list of values?

Comment: @user469104 ComboBox has many Items. If manual entry is not allowed then user cannot search items.

Comment: Setting `IsEditable=true` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, I have set IsEditable=true and it works fine, but the problem is caused as asked in the question.

Comment: I've done a quick sample and I don't understand. In my case, each time a new key is pressed in the combobox, the selectedvalue setter is fired...

Comment: Ok wait,now I see...if you click in another control and go back to the combo it lets you write behind the text without firing the selecteditem setter...

Comment: In your XAML you set `SelectedValue="{Binding ItemId,  .........`, . Have you got `ItemId` defined in your ViewModel? I believe you should use `SelectedItemId` instead, or is this a typo.

Comment: @Bolu Actually the Combobox is inside a ListItem and that listbox is bound to a Collection.

Comment: @Vishal See my answer...it seems a bit complicated but i couldn't find another way. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error when the binding is set correctly.

Comment: @Bolu Error is always reproduced even if the binding is set correctly. user Pikoh has already reproduced the error.

Comment: @Pikoh can you please post your sample project that reproduced the error? Because user Bolu wants that. I can create a sample project and post it here, but since you have done it, there is no meaning in wasting time.

Comment: Vishal I can't post my sample project as it is part of a bigger one sorry. @Bolu, the problem is not with the binding, i've been able to reproduce it with correct binding. The problem arises when you select a value from the combobox, after that setting the focus in another control and then going back to the combo. In that case, it lets you write characters after the ones there and does not fire the SelectedValue setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you want to Set `SelectedValue` to 0 when there is any validation error in the editable `TextBox` of the`ComboBox`. You need to check the validation result of the `Text` and then reset your `SelectedValue` to 0 if the validation fails.

Here is an working example for you:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" 
                      IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="ItemName"
                      Text="{Binding SelectedName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
                      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">                
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedID,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;    
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MyViewModel mvm;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mvm = new MyViewModel()
            {
                ComboboxItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboItem>() 
                { 
                    new ComboItem{ItemName="item1",ItemId=1},
                    new ComboItem{ItemName="item2",ItemId=2},
                    new ComboItem{ItemName="item3",ItemId=3}
                },
            };
            this.DataContext = mvm;
        }
    }
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public class ComboItem : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _itemname;
        private int _itemid;
        public string ItemName
        {
            get
            {
                return _itemname;
            }
            set
            {
                _itemname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ItemName");
            }
        }

        public int ItemId
        {
            get { return _itemid; }
            set
            {
                _itemid = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ItemId");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private int _selectedid;
        private string _selectedname;
        public ObservableCollection<ComboItem> ComboboxItems
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public int SelectedID
        {
            get { return _selectedid; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedid != value)
                {
                    _selectedid = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedID");

                }
            }
        }
        public string SelectedName
        {
            get { return _selectedname; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedname != value)
                {
                    _selectedname = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedName");

                }
            }
        }   

        public string Error
        {
            get { return this[SelectedName]; }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get {

                switch (columnName)
                {
                    case "SelectedName":
                        {
                            if (SelectedName!=null && ComboboxItems.Count(x => x.ItemName == SelectedName) == 0)
                            {
                                //reset selected value to 0
                                this.SelectedID = 0;
                                return "Invalid selection";

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

When user enter valid text (e.g. item1), the `Textbox` below shows the correct `ItemId` of the `SelectedValue`, and when user enter invalid text, the selected value will be reset to 0.

[image: result]

P.S: When garbage is entered in `ComboBox`, it will always display validation error indicator (red border as shown above), and if you data-bind `SelectedItem` to a property, it will be null. So you shouldn't care about the `SelectedValue` if there is an error, that's why I was saying I can't reproduce the error in the comments.

Comment: Bolu see my coment in OP question. To reproduce the problem, put for example a TextBox in your sample project. Select a value in the combo, click in the textbox and go back to the combo. It selects all the text, click once to unselect it, and write anything after that. You'll see the setter of `SelectedValue`is not fired

Comment: @Pikoh, thanks for the info. my answer is to address that.

Comment: I have spend my whole day on this problem and at last I rely on your solution. It was very handy. Thank you very much @Bolu ........

Answer (score 2):

You really got me with this, i've never realized this problem existed. I've found a solution that works it you don't care to clear the combo on focus. There are probably better ways, but none i can think about. Maybe someone out there has another solution.

First of all, add a reference to `Windows.System.Interactivity` in your proyect, and add this to your XAML:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Then, add this code to the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ItemsCompColl}" 
      TextSearch.TextPath="ItemName" x:Name="cbItems"
      SelectedValue="{Binding ItemId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotMouseCapture">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClearCombo}" 
               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cbItems}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Finally, let's create the command in ouw View Model:

```
RelayCommand<System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox> _clearCombo;
public ICommand ClearCombo
{
    get
    {
        if (_clearCombo == null)
        {
            _clearCombo = new RelayCommand<System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox>(this.ClearComboCommandExecuted,
            param => this.ClearComboCommandCanExecute());

        }
        return _clearCombo;
    }
}

private bool ClearComboCommandCanExecute()
{
    return true;
}

private void ClearComboCommandExecuted(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb)
{
    cb.Text = "";
}
```

Hope this helps with your problem.

**Edit**

Ok, after @XAMlMAX comment, I think he is right and this may be done in Code Behind easily and probably it's better in MVVM pattern. Simply add a event handler to the combobox to capture `GotMouseCapture`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ItemsCompColl}" 
      TextSearch.TextPath="ItemName" x:Name="cbItems"
      SelectedValue="{Binding ItemId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
      GotMouseCapture="cbItems_GotMouseCapture" >
```

And then in code behind of the View:

```
private void cbItems_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   ((ComboBox)sender).Text = "";
}
```

**Edit 2**

Well, one final, ugly idea to solve it. I don't like it at all, but maybe it solves your problem.

First of all, you must subscribe to the `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` event:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ItemsCompColl}" 
      TextSearch.TextPath="ItemName" x:Name="cbItems"
      SelectedValue="{Binding ItemId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectedValuePath="ItemId"
      Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" 
      TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cbItems_TextChanged" >
```

Then in code behind add this code:

```
private void cbItems_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
   ((YourViewModel)this.DataContext).ItemId= text;
}
```

This way, you make sure any time the `ComboBox` changes its text, you get notified about it. It's really horrible code, but i've runned out of ideas...

Comment: Great work @Pikoh!!!! But what I want to say you is that if you clear the text of the ComboBox, then there will be a problem. Let me explain you. When user is editing an item and wants to go from first field to last field by just pressing enter or tab key, he will pass through the combobox and he has to select the data in combobox again.

Comment: Hmm...didn't thought of that. Maybe tomorrow if i have time will think of a solution for that. Maybe instead of using `gotfocus` use another event like `click`...

Comment: Great news you got this fixed, but there is no reason for `ViewModel` to have UI elements inside of it! You broke the MvvM rule for separation of concerns, the best way to do this would be in code-behind. Apart from that well done to find the solution.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Well, viemodel has not UI element inside, it just gets a reference to one. I agree it is not pure MVVM probably, but I don't think it would be a problem for example to unit testing it. Anyway, you can probably give us a better solution with the code in the code behind of the view. I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Vishal try my edited answer...just change in the event name `GotFocus` for `GotMouseCapture`. That way it wouldn't erase the value entering in the combo with a tab.

Comment: @Vishal of course. But if you click in the combo, I guess you want to change its Value??? Other thing is that you are using tab to move between controls and it may fall in the combobox without you wanting to change it value. My last edit address that.

Comment: @Pikoh If you change the event then also there will be a problem. If user enters the ComboBox using Keyboard and enters some garbage value then again the same problem will arise. I think we should think of a new approach

Comment: Yes that's it. It is a good solution. But I am a pure MVVM guy and so, I used the mixed solutions from you and the other user @Bolu along with the nice post here: http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.in/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html and http://cid-890c06c8106550a0.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/BlogSamples/JoyfulWPF/DemoCommandAction%7C_KeyDown.zip Thank you very much both of you.